# NumberFormatException: For input string: "" JAVA

Tags: java, conversión-de-tipos

```
    public void logicaaritmetica() {

        TercerV tv2 = new TercerV();
        FirstClass fc = new FirstClass() {

            @Override
            public void logicaaritmetica() {

            }
        };


       try {
            String tjt  = (tv2.jttv.getText().trim());
            fc.setA(Integer.parseInt(tjt));

            if ((fc.getA() >= 0) && (fc.getA() <= 1000000)) {
                fc.setBalance(fc.getA() - fc.getBalance());

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad es superior o 
                inferior al limite posible");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e);
        }
    }
```

Quiero convertir el contenido del textfield a string y luego a int, pero me sale error, como ven guardo el texto en una variable y luego convierto enviando el entero a una variable privada de tipo int en otra clase utilizando el metodo Integer.parseInt.

pero aun asi el codigo sigue diciendome que le estoy introduciendo texto cuando acciono ese metodo con un boton.

Comment: El argumento de Integer.ParseInt debe ser un numero valido. No puede convertir un empty string ("")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error:

> NumberFormatException: For input string: “”

Te está dando porque al `textfield` le esta llegando una cadena vacía.

Otros posibles errores pueden ser por:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "null" means input was null.
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "F1" means input was F1 which is alphanumeric
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "1.0" means input String was "1.0" and you were trying to
>   convert it to Integral data type e.g. int, short, char and byte.

Asegúrate que a tu variable `tv2.jttv.getText().trim()` le llegue un valor correcto para después hacer `fc.setA(Integer.parseInt(tjt));`

Te dejo un escenario parecido al tuyo:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String entrada = "123344";
        int numero;
        String tjt  = (entrada.trim());
        numero = (Integer.parseInt(tjt));

        try {
            if ((numero >= 0) && (numero <= 1000000)) {
                System.out.println("Correcto ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error catch");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/DtRXcN5 

ahi puedes ver que lo que le asigno de entrada al textfield son enteros e igual me tira error

Comment: ya resolvi, movi parte de el codigo al boton y ahora si obtiene el valor

Comment: Genial! Me alegra que lo hayas solucionado :)