# Recoger datos de un form y pasarlos a otra clase

Tags: java, class

Reformulo pregunta que no sabía como iba esto:
Tengo un Formulario con varios datos a rellenar ,en otro paquete tengo una clase con los métodos que quiero usar para que me calcule lo que me pide el formulario, al rellenar y capturar el evento en el botón, me da error de empty string. Si lo hago todo dentro del formulario (estructurado) me da correcto, no me peta el programa con el String vacío, pero me gustaría tenerlo bien organizado con los métodos aparte.
El método recoge los float que hay de cada Jlabel de cada talla, hace la media y lo tendría que setear en un lbl (lbl_consumoMedio) luego hacer multiplicación del consumo(consumo medio * precio metro ) e introducido en Jtextfield y este resultado setearlo en un JtextField .Luego introduciendo los costes de cada Jtextfield ( más el resultado de la multiplicación) tendría que calcular el precio de coste y setearlo en un Jlabel ( lbl_ResultadoCoste_CamMC)

CLASE MËTODOS:

```
public class MetEscCamFutbolMC extends EscCamFutbolMC{
   
   //atributos
   protected String tejido;
   protected float precioMtTejido,consumo_XXL,consumo_XL,consumo_L,consumo_M,consumo_S,consumo_XS,consumo_XXS,consMedio;
   protected  float  precioTejido,precioCorte,precioCalandra,precioPloter,precioCosido;
   protected float precioCoste,tantPerCent,precioVenta;

   //constructor
   public MetEscCamFutbolMC() {
       this.tejido=tejido;
       this.precioMtTejido=precioMtTejido;
       this.consumo_XXL=consumo_XXL;
       this.consumo_XL=consumo_XL;
       this.consumo_L=consumo_L;
       this.consumo_M=consumo_M;
       this.consumo_S=consumo_S;
       this.consumo_XS=consumo_XS;
       this.consumo_XXS=consumo_XXS;
       this.consMedio=consMedio;
       this.precioTejido=precioTejido;
       this.precioCorte=precioCorte;
       this.precioCalandra=precioCalandra;
       this.precioPloter=precioPloter;
       this.precioCosido=precioCosido;
       this.precioCoste=precioCoste;
       this.tantPerCent=tantPerCent;
       this.precioVenta=precioVenta;
   
   }

   //getters y setters
   public String getTejido() {
       return tejido;
   }

   public void setTejido(String tejido) {
       this.tejido = tejido;
   }

   public float getPrecioMtTejido() {
       return precioMtTejido;
   }

   public void setPrecioMtTejido(float precioMtTejido) {
       this.precioMtTejido = precioMtTejido;
   }

   public float getConsumo_XXL() {
       return consumo_XXL;
   }

   public void setConsumo_XXL(float consumo_XXL) {
       this.consumo_XXL = consumo_XXL;
   }

   public float getConsumo_XL() {
       return consumo_XL;
   }

   public void setConsumo_XL(float consumo_XL) {
       this.consumo_XL = consumo_XL;
   }

   public float getConsumo_L() {
       return consumo_L;
   }

 //instancio objeto
   EscCamFutbolMC escCamFutbolMC = new EscCamFutbolMC();
   
   
   //metodos propios
   public float consumoMedio(){
    
    precioMtTejido = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtPrecioMetro.getText());
       
    consumo_XXL = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XXL.getText());
    consumo_XL = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XL.getText());
    consumo_L = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_L.getText());
    consumo_M = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_M.getText());
    consumo_S = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_S.getText());
    consumo_XS = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XS.getText());
    consumo_XXS = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XXS.getText());
    consMedio = (consumo_XXL + consumo_XL + consumo_L + consumo_M + consumo_S + consumo_XS + consumo_XXS)/ 7;
    escCamFutbolMC.lbl_consumoMedio.setText(String.valueOf(consMedio));
    
    precioTejido = precioMtTejido * consMedio;
    escCamFutbolMC.txtPrecioMedioTejido_camMC.setText(String.valueOf(precioTejido));
    
    precioCorte = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtCorte_CamMC.getText());
    precioCalandra = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtCalandra_CamMC.getText());
    precioPloter = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtPlotter_CamMC.getText());
    precioCosido = Float.parseFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtCosido_CamMC.getText());
    
    precioCoste = precioTejido + precioCorte + precioCalandra + precioPloter + precioCosido;
    escCamFutbolMC.lbl_ResultadoCoste_CamMC.setText(String.valueOf(precioCoste));
    
    return precioCoste;
   
   }
```

los getters y setter lo he recortado para no extender mucho el código

EN EL FORMULARIO:
[image: img formulario]

```
 private void 
           btnCalcularMediaChaleco2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                                                         
      MetEscCamFutbolMC metEscCamFut = new MetEscCamFutbolMC();
      metEscCamFut.consumoMedio();
     
    }
```

ERROR:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
> at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:461)     at
> Metodos.Escandall.MetEscCamFutbolMC.consumoMedio(MetEscCamFutbolMC.java:195)
> at
> Escandall.EscCamFutbolMC.btnCalcularMediaChaleco2ActionPerformed(EscCamFutbolMC.java:409)
> at
> Escandall.EscCamFutbolMC$5.actionPerformed(EscCamFutbolMC.java:378)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)

Espero haberlo escrito mejor. Muchas gracias ante todo

Comment: Hola, con lo que nos muestras de tu código, es imposible saber que pasa, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar los métodos que están relacionados con el problema?, y si es necesario, una explicación de lo que hacen.

Comment: que es EscCamFutbolMC? de donde se supone que el constructor toma los datos?

Comment: Hola gbianchi gracias por responder, no se si se responde así  ( soy nuevo en este mundo) , EscCamFutbolMC es el formulario,quizás si pongo captura  me explicaría mejor, la idea es , rellenar el formulario, las operaciones en otra clase y devolver el resultado al formulario otra vez.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [NumberFormatException: For input string: "" JAVA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294282/numberformatexception-for-input-string-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
public float consumoMedio() {

    precioMtTejido = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.txtPrecioMetro.getText() );
       
    consumo_XXL = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XXL.getText() );
    consumo_XL = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XL.getText() );
    consumo_L = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_L.getText() );
    consumo_M = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_M.getText() );
    consumo_S = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_S.getText() );
    consumo_XS = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XS.getText() );
    consumo_XXS = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XXS.getText() );

    consMedio = ( consumo_XXL + consumo_XL + consumo_L + consumo_M + consumo_S + consumo_XS + consumo_XXS )/ 7;
    escCamFutbolMC.lbl_consumoMedio.setText( String.valueOf( consMedio ));
    
    precioTejido = precioMtTejido * consMedio;
    escCamFutbolMC.txtPrecioMedioTejido_camMC.setText( String.valueOf( precioTejido ));
    
    precioCorte = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.txtCorte_CamMC.getText() );
    precioCalandra = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.txtCalandra_CamMC.getText() );
    precioPloter = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.txtPlotter_CamMC.getText() );
    precioCosido = convierte( escCamFutbolMC.txtCosido_CamMC.getText());
    
    precioCoste = precioTejido + precioCorte + precioCalandra + precioPloter + precioCosido;    escCamFutbolMC.lbl_ResultadoCoste_CamMC.setText( String.valueOf( precioCoste ));    
    return precioCoste;
   
}

void convierte( String texto ) {
    if( ! text.equals("") && text != null ) {   
        return Float.parseFloat( text );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El error que te devuelve el sistema, es que estás intentando parsear a Float un String vacio, suponiendo que sea correcto que el mismo este vacio, creé un método que verifica que el String no este vacio ni sea nulo, si no lo es, devuelve el valor parseado y sino devuelve ***0***.
Te dejo una observación, el constructor de la clase **MetEscCamFutbolMC**, no recibe ningún argumento, por lo que debería estar vacío, o lo que es lo mismo, no escrito (el propio lenguaje se encarga de crear un constructor vacío si no encuentra al menos un constructor en la clase).
Espero que esto solucione tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Al obtener el error `NumberFormatException`, indica que tratas de convertir un valor no numerico a float. Lo que debes hacer es validar estos casos y usando el siguiente mètodo:

```
  public static float getFloat(String valor) {
     float resultado = 0; //valor predeterminado si no es numerico.
     try {
       resultado = Float.parseFloat(valor);
       return resultado;
     } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
       return resultado; 
     }     
  }
```

usalo en tu còdigo de esta forma:

```
 //metodos propios
   public float consumoMedio(){
    
    precioMtTejido = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtPrecioMetro.getText());
       
    consumo_XXL = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XXL.getText());
    consumo_XL = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XL.getText());
    consumo_L = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_L.getText());
    consumo_M = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_M.getText());
    consumo_S = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_S.getText());
    consumo_XS = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XS.getText());
    consumo_XXS = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.lblConsum_XXS.getText());
    consMedio = (consumo_XXL + consumo_XL + consumo_L + consumo_M + consumo_S + consumo_XS + consumo_XXS)/ 7;
    escCamFutbolMC.lbl_consumoMedio.setText(String.valueOf(consMedio));
    
    precioTejido = precioMtTejido * consMedio;
    escCamFutbolMC.txtPrecioMedioTejido_camMC.setText(String.valueOf(precioTejido));
    
    precioCorte = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtCorte_CamMC.getText());
    precioCalandra = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtCalandra_CamMC.getText());
    precioPloter = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtPlotter_CamMC.getText());
    precioCosido = getFloat(escCamFutbolMC.txtCosido_CamMC.getText());
    
    precioCoste = precioTejido + precioCorte + precioCalandra + precioPloter + precioCosido;
    escCamFutbolMC.lbl_ResultadoCoste_CamMC.setText(String.valueOf(precioCoste));
    
    return precioCoste;
   
   }
```

De esta forma, al tener un valor no numérico en tus vistas `JtextField` o `Jlabel` y tratar de convertirlo, tu programa no generaría un error.